# phpinfo() changes the status code of nginx response in a weird way

Tags: php, nginx, php-7, php-7.1

I have a php code that should always end up being "http 500 code" as I have a call to undefined func `status_code("OK");`

**code**:

```php
<?
# phpinfo();
echo 'error_log = ' . ini_get('error_log') . "\n";
status_code("OK");
echo "OK";
?>
```

**With example above:**

```
➜ curl -I http://localhost:8080/kkk
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Server: nginx/1.20.1
Date: Sat, 29 Oct 2022 18:48:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 5597
Connection: close
ETag: "635c9b20-15dd"
```

and in stdout output:

```
2022/10/29 18:50:32 [error] 29#29: *30 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function status_code() in /legacy/app/index.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /legacy/app/index.php on line 4" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.17.0.1, server: localhost, request: "HEAD /kkk HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost:8080"
172.17.0.1 - - [29/Oct/2022:18:50:32 +0000] 500 "HEAD /kkk HTTP/1.1" 0 "-" "curl/7.82.0" "-"
```

**However if I uncomment `#phpinfo();` line I get 200 OK:**

```bash
➜ curl -I http://localhost:8080/kkk
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.20.1
Date: Sat, 29 Oct 2022 18:52:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.33
```

and in stdout:

```bash
172.17.0.1 - - [29/Oct/2022:18:52:25 +0000] 200 "HEAD /kkk HTTP/1.1" 0 "-" "curl/7.82.0" "-"
```

I'm running nginx and it has the following configuration:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    root /legacy/app;
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 10s;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 16k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 16k;
}

location / {
    # make sure you have a custom html page placed in app folder
    # i.e. /legacy/app/app/50x.html
    try_files _ /index.php?$query_string;

}
```

Comment: status code as well as headers must be set before any output is produced

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use builtin function [`http_response_code()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.http-response-code.php) to change the response code.

But, as well as `header()`, you **must** call `http_response_code()` before `phpinfo()` because any output produced in your response will imply header with 200 status code that you can't change anymore. (see [Call header() after output is sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263364/call-header-after-output-is-sent))

Just tested with `Apache` (I don't think it makes a difference).

This **works** (display php info with 500 status code):

```php
http_response_code(500);
phpinfo();
```

This *doesn't works* (display php info with 200 status code):

```php
phpinfo();
http_response_code(500);
```

This *doesn't works* (display php info with 200 status code):

```php
phpinfo();
undefined_function(); // generates an error in error.log
```

Comment: thanks @Chris, it's interesting I have expected that there is a call to `undefined_function();` - php fastcgi reports back as error and waits for all data from the index.php before starting the response to nginx.